# Cannot Position Div, I'm sure it's something VERY simple

Tags: css

I'm trying to position my form but cannot seem to get it to move... Specifically the div "box"

I'm sure I'm doing something simple. I just need to be able to position the "box" div within the wrapper div.

Thank you!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Instant Discount</title>
  <style type="text/css">
.WRAPPER {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 575px;
    width: 975px;
    background-image: url(exit-gate/exit-gate-bg2.png);
    top: auto;
    margin: -8px;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
} 
box {
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
}
#email {
    background: transparent;
    color:white;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    height:30px;
    transition:height 1s;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s;
}
#email:focus {
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:14px;
}
  </style>

 </head>
  <body>



<div class="WRAPPER">


 <div class="box">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
    <input type="image" src="exit-gate/white-box-10.png" alt="{alternate text}" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP's typo

Comment: Also don't forget to [validate your html](http://validator.w3.org/). Looks like you have an extra `</div>` floating around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your css selector is wrong:

Should be `.box {` not `box {`.

Comment: ... it was, _in fact_, something simple! +! =D

Comment: `.` is for classes, `#` is for ID's. `body` is an exception to this rule though.

Comment: Hey guys, I really appreciate it!!!  Little bits of help like that make my novice life much easier.  I seriously spent 30 minutes trying to figure it out.  Thanks again!

Comment: @HoustonGuy Yes, well we have all been in oh-crap-it-was-just-missing-a-[insert punctuation here] hell!

Comment: @HoustonGuy  Also, don't be saddened when your question is closed. Your typo is unlikely to help future users, and you did get a answer :P I tossed you an upvote to counter-act the downvotes